# How do I unmarshall this XACML XML snippet using JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xacml, xacml3

```
<Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"
    PolicyId="ClientType"
    RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:first-applicable"
    Version="1.0">
<Target>
<AnyOf>
            <AllOf>
                <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                    <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Reply</AttributeValue>
                    <AttributeDesignator
                        AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id"
                        Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action"
                        DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true" />
                </Match>
            </AllOf>
        </AnyOf>
    </Target>

    <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="Rule_for_all">
        <Target>
            <AnyOf>
                <AllOf>
                    <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">A</AttributeValue>
                        <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="Reply"
                            Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject"
                            DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true" />
                    </Match>
                </AllOf>
            </AnyOf>
        </Target>
    </Rule>
    <Rule Effect="deny" RuleId="Rule_deny_all" />
</Policy>
```

Please help me to unmarshall this xml using JAXB. I tried doing it but in between I got confused and got error. I have a quite big xml file but this fragment will help me understand.

Comment: By the way, what's the error your are getting?

Answer (score 2):

The fragment you sent is actually an incomplete XML fragment. It's lacking for instance the closing `</Policy>` element.

The fragment you sent corresponds to a XACML 3.0 policy. This means that before you close the policy you should also have 1 or more rules (technically the schema does allow zero rules but that doesn't make sense).

To marshall and unmarshall using JAX-B, you need to use the XACML 3.0 schema which you can find [here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-core-v3-schema-wd-17.xsd). It's pretty straightforward to configure JAXB to create the Java objects based on that schema. You'll need to create a simple XJB file to configure the marshalling.

That said, considering there are several XACML engines out there (both open source and vendor such as the one I work for, [Axiomatics](http://www.axiomatics.com)), what's your rationale for implementing a XACML parser yourself?

Cheers,
David.

Comment: I have updated the xml for better understanding. Please have a look. All I need to do is to cache the rules from this xacml policy file. I need to extract the rules

Comment: +1, @Nik - Here is an example of generating a model from XML schema and using it to marshal/unmarshal XML: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/processing-atom-feeds-with-jaxb.html